# Using of min and max in the navigator

Tags: highcharts

I'm working on a long term project and in the beginning of the new release I updated the Highstock version from 1.3.8 to 2.1.2. I didn't make any major changes in the StockChart configuration but I notice that the min and max settings for the navigation don't work as the previous version of the Highstock. So, here are the comparison of the charts with the old version and the new one:
[image]

[image]

And you can see in the new version the navigation doesn't apply the **min** value for the navigation.

Also I reproduce the problem in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vangi/fpnayfuq/6/) and here is the code:

```js
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        navigator: {
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                ordinal: false,
                min: Date.UTC(2015, 0, 28),
                max: Date.UTC(2015, 1, 26)
            },
            series: {
                data: [
                    [Date.UTC(2015, 0, 21), 0.1],
                    [Date.UTC(2015, 0, 30), 2.84],
                    [Date.UTC(2015, 1, 2), 2.79],
                    [Date.UTC(2015, 1, 3), 2.79],
                    [Date.UTC(2015, 1, 4), 3.04],
                    [Date.UTC(2015, 1, 5), 3.04],
                    [Date.UTC(2015, 1, 10), 1.70],
                    [Date.UTC(2015, 1, 11), 1.67]
                ]
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            ordinal: false,
            min: Date.UTC(2015, 0, 28),
            max: Date.UTC(2015, 1, 26)
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Serie1',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2015, 0, 21), 0.1],
                [Date.UTC(2015, 0, 30), 2.84],
                [Date.UTC(2015, 1, 2), 2.79],
                [Date.UTC(2015, 1, 3), 2.79],
                [Date.UTC(2015, 1, 4), 3.04],
                [Date.UTC(2015, 1, 5), 3.04],
                [Date.UTC(2015, 1, 10), 1.70],
                [Date.UTC(2015, 1, 11), 1.67]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/usdeur.js"></script>
```

Can you help me to configure the Highstock to behave like in the previous version? Did I miss some parameters to configure? Is this normal behavior of the new version or it is a bug?

Comment: In 1.3.8 it not looks like properly (http://jsfiddle.net/fpnayfuq/7/) but have you tried to call [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes) to define range on axis?

Comment: Setting of the extremes don't work also: http://jsfiddle.net/Vangi/fpnayfuq/9/.

Comment: So you expect that full range will be on xAxis navigator, correct?

Comment: Yes the full range should be on xAxis navigator. That's mean the xAxis navigator to start from the given 'min' date (Date.UTC(2015, 0, 28)) instead of the first date of the navigator data (Date.UTC(2015, 0, 21)). And space marked with red rectangle as in the screenshot before should disappear.

Comment: The simplest way is set ALL in rangeselector by option: selected. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fpnayfuq/10/

Comment: In my application I don't use range selector and I don't want to show the entire data. We load data with AJAX request and the user can specify the time range for the data to be shown but we should indicate to the user there is data before. Therefore we have an additional point in front but we want to show only the time range that is specified. It was possible before to set this by add "min" setting of the navigator axis but it doesn't works now.